# High School Physics student needs help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

A human cannon has a spring constant of 35 000 N/m. The spring can be extended up to 4.5m. How far horizontally would a 65kg clown be fired if the cannon is pointed upward at 45 degrees to the horizontal?

Comment: Are you familiar with ideal springs?  Do you know the formula for working with them?  You need to show some level of effort.

Answer (score 1):

Max. Energy in spring=$\dfrac12 kx^2$
that will get transfered into body of mass m=$65kg$
.
So, $$\dfrac12 kx^2=\dfrac12 mv^2$$

here you get the velocity and then solve for range $$R\text{ange}=\dfrac{u^2sin(2\theta)}{g}=\dfrac{u^2}{g}\Bigg|_{\theta=45}$$